# DeserializeObject json c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

i have

```
 dynamic json

"items": {
          "ids": [
            "some text",
            "some text",
          ],

        },
```

i try to add some ids but wrong

my try

```
     List<string> list_json = new List<string>();
 list_json.Add('some text2');
            dynamic json_response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resp);
        json_response.items.ids = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list_json);
```

but if i inspect my result i get

```
"ids": 
 "[\"some text2\"]",
```

what wrong?

Comment: That's the expected output: JsonConvert.SerializeObject *returns a string*, in this case the *content* of the JSON *string* is `["some text2"]`. The "extra stuff" comes when *using the **string*** to build further output. It might as well have been: `json_response.items.ids = "\"Honey,\" I'm home!";`

Comment: (tldr; assign the *list* to the id fields so the collection will be serialized as part of the response JSON correctly)

Comment: You have to create the `items` object. `json_response.items = new { ids = ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use dynamic, I'd created objects for the JSON you are trying to work with. Something like this would work:

```
void Main()
{
     var jsonString = @"{""Items"": {
                         ""Ids"": [
                             ""sometext"",
                             ""sometext""
                           ]
                        }}";

    var items = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
}


public class RootObject {
    public Items Items {get;set;}
}

public class Items {
    public List<string> Ids {get;set;}
}
```

With this you would then be able to access the list of Ids

with `var ids = items.Ids`